# Scrapy - Get all data within selector

Tags: xpath, scrapy

If I have some HTML in the response that looks like:

```
<body>
    Body text
    <div>
        Div text
    </div>
</body>
```

If I do `response.xpath('//body/text()').extract()` I will only get `[Body text]`

I want to get **everything** inside `<body>` including the tags i.e. this whole thing:

```
Body text
<div>
    Div text
</div>
```

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
response.xpath('//body/node()/text()')
```

Or if you want the tags too:

```
response.xpath('//body/node()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//body/(descendant::text() | following::text())
```

or

```
//body/descendant::text() | //body/following::text()
```