# How can I get all text data of a node with xpath in scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape user review data from a website. I hope to have a 2 column data (ratings and reviews) at the end.

Here is a sample xml file that emulates my scraping problem. I have tried it on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output.to get the outputs.

```
<root>
  <div class="user-review">
    <div class="rating"> 5,0 </div>
    <p class="review-content"> Reiew text of item/movie.
      <span class="details">
          <span class="details-header">Detail: </span>
      <span class="details-content">Some details to emphasis</span>
      </span>
      Continue to review
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-review">
    <div class="rating"> 4,0 </div>
    <p class="review-content">Reiew text of item/movie.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-review">
    <div class="rating"> 4,0 </div>
    <p class="review-content">Reiew text of item/movie.
    </p>
  </div>
</root>
```

I can get 3 rating values with query below.

```
/root/div/div[@class="rating"]/text()
```

Output:

```
Text=' 5,0 '
Text=' 4,0 '
Text=' 4,0 '
```

When I try to get the review part the first text is divided into 2 sections. Because of that I have two different sized lists(3 sized ratings and 4 sized reviews) and cannot match reviews with ratings

```
//p[@class="review-content"]/text()
```

Output:

```
Text='  Reiew text of item/movie.
        '
Text='
Continue to review
    '
Text='Reiew text of item/movie.
    '
Text='Reiew text of item/movie.
```

Can anybody help me to get one of my expected ouputs?

Expected output1:

```
Text='  Reiew text of item/movie.
    Continue to review
    '
Text='Reiew text of item/movie.
    '
Text='Reiew text of item/movie.
```

Expected output2:

```
Text='  Reiew text of item/movie. Some details to emphasis
    Continue to review
    '
Text='Reiew text of item/movie.
    '
Text='Reiew text of item/movie.
```

Comment: this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586271/scrapy-get-all-data-within-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop over `div` elements with `user-review` class and extract the review content from each of these. If you want a one-liner, look at this:

```
import scrapy

text = """
<root>
  <div class="user-review">
    <div class="rating"> 5,0 </div>
    <p class="review-content"> Reiew text of item/movie.
      <span class="details">
          <span class="details-header">Detail: </span>
      <span class="details-content">Some details to emphasis</span>
      </span>
      Continue to review
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-review">
    <div class="rating"> 4,0 </div>
    <p class="review-content">Reiew text of item/movie.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-review">
    <div class="rating"> 4,0 </div>
    <p class="review-content">Reiew text of item/movie.
    </p>
  </div>
</root>
"""

selector = scrapy.Selector(text=text)
review_content = [review.xpath('normalize-space(.//p[@class="review-content"])').extract_first() for review in selector.xpath('//div[@class="user-review"]')]
```

Comment: There should be selector instead of sel in last line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, sel is here selector, in your case may be response

```
tags = sel.xpath('//p[@class="review-content"]')
reviews = []
for tag in tags:
    text = " ".join(tag.xpath('.//text()').extract())
    reviews.append(text)
```